# Sharepoint 2013 - how to make a column content bold in task list

Tags: column

I am struggling with making any content under the 'Task Name' column in bold. I am using Sharepoint 2013. I have a task list (classic) and I want to make each task name in Bold. I would like to add a script editor web part and add code but I do not know what code to insert.
Could you help with this?
Thank you very much
Valeria

Answer (score 0):

You can try JSLink feature for customizing the columns